# Array delete - last entry duplicated

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have code which deletes an entry from an array and then moves all the elements down one index so the empty space will be left at the end of the array. The problem is that the last entry in the array is duplicated into the deleted index.

This is the array when all the records are entered:

`[entryOne, entryTwo, entryThree, entryFour, entryFive, entrySix, entrySeven, entryEight, entryNine, entryTen]`

I then run my code to delete index 5 and print the array, this is what is shown:

`[entryOne, entryTwo, entryThree, entryFour, entryFive, entrySeven, entryEight, entryNine, entryTen, entryTen]`

How can I get the final index to be emptied?

Add record code:

```
  static void addStudent() {
    if (nameArrayCount < 10) {
      System.out.println("Enter the student's name in the following format - surname, forename: ");
      studentName = input.next();
      studentNamesArray[nameArrayCount] = studentName;
      nameArrayCount = nameArrayCount + 1;
    }
    else if (nameArrayCount == 10) {
      System.out.println("******Array is full, please delete a student before adding another.*****");
    }
    if (markArrayCount < 10){
    System.out.println("Enter the first mark: ");
          markOne = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter the second mark: ");
          markTwo = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter the third mark: ");
          markThree = input.nextInt();
          studentMarksArray[markArrayCount][0] = markOne;
          studentMarksArray[markArrayCount][1] = markTwo;
          studentMarksArray[markArrayCount][2] = markThree;
          markArrayCount = markArrayCount + 1;
    }
  }
```

Delete record code:

```
  static void deleteStudent() {
    System.out.println("Which student would you like to delete?");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
    }
    int studentChoice = input.nextInt();
    for(int i = studentChoice+1; i<studentNamesArray.length; i++) {
      studentNamesArray[i-1] = studentNamesArray[i];
    }
    nameArrayCount = nameArrayCount -1;
  }
```

Comment: Assuming your array holds objects or strings, set the last one to null.  You cannot resize the array however.  Have you considered using a List instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to manually set it to `null`.

```
for(int i = studentChoice+1; i<studentNamesArray.length; i++) {
      studentNamesArray[i-1] = studentNamesArray[i];
}

studentNamesArray[studentNamesArray.length - 1] = null;
```

If you're going to do this, you might want to use an `ArrayList` instead though. It's a lot better for removing/adding values. There's also a `toArray()` method available which will allow you to return it in array form if really needed (I don't expect this code sample to use that many student entries that this would be an expensive operation).

Comment: If for any case, lists should not be used, one can use `System.arraycopy` to copy the array into a smaller one.